# In Python, what is the fastest algorithm for removing duplicates from a list so that all elements are unique *while preserving order*?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

For example:

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 2, 'a', 'a', 3]
>>> unique(x)
[1, 2, 'a', 3]
```

Assume list elements are hashable.

**Clarification:** The result should keep the first duplicate in the list. For example, [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1] becomes [1, 2, 3].

Comment: Are we keeping the first of duplicates, or last, or somewhere in the middle? e.g., [1,2,3,2,3,1], does that become [1,2,3], or [2,3,1], or something else?

Comment: Benchmark and a clear answer [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark).

Comment: How Do I apply the Homework tag to something?  When it says assume elements are hashable, your prof is asking you to put the entries in a hashtable, then it's easy to see if youve come across them before as you walk down the list.

Answer (score 33):

```
def unique(items):
    found = set()
    keep = []

    for item in items:
        if item not in found:
            found.add(item)
            keep.append(item)
            
    return keep

print unique([1, 1, 2, 'a', 'a', 3])
```

Comment: set() is better than set([]).

Comment: In-place algorithms are faster. See james' and mine answers.

Comment: This is an old thread, but if you make the add() and append() methods local function (put `add = found.add` and `app = keep.append` before the loop and then use `add(item)` and `app(item)`, then this is the fastest by far. The reason that the dictionary usage was faster was that it didn't require an attribute look-up for each add and append. Just my two cents.

Comment: If you put it into a list comprehension afterwards, you get another speed improvement. Taking all the changes together, speed nearly doubles. See my comparison further down this page.

Comment: @JustinPeel: have you tried to run [the benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so/282589?noredirect=1#comment10841935_282589)?

Comment: Why is the `set()` needed at all? Why isn't it enough to test membership of `item in items` against `keep[]`?

Comment: @so.very.tired Because `keep` is a list, and checking for membership in a list takes on average linear time in the length of the list. Meanwhile, checking for membership in a set takes on average constant time (see [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)). Using appropriate data structures is a deal breaker when it comes to performance. In any case, this answer is outdated. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) instead.

Comment: Note: This is a simpler version of [the `itertools` module's `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (the recipe improves upon it a bit, performance-wise, by pushing more work to the C layer and making the function a generator, so unique items are produced immediately when seen, rather than having to wait for the whole input to be processed before you can process any of them, and reducing the storage to just a `set`, not a `set` *and* `list` containing the same elements).

Answer (score 21):

Using:

```
lst = [8, 8, 9, 9, 7, 15, 15, 2, 20, 13, 2, 24, 6, 11, 7, 12, 4, 10, 18, 13, 23, 11, 3, 11, 12, 10, 4, 5, 4, 22, 6, 3, 19, 14, 21, 11, 1, 5, 14, 8, 0, 1, 16, 5, 10, 13, 17, 1, 16, 17, 12, 6, 10, 0, 3, 9, 9, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 5, 14, 18, 12, 19, 2, 8, 9, 0, 8, 4, 5]
```

And using the timeit module:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import uniquetest' 'uniquetest.etchasketch(uniquetest.lst)'
```

And so on for the various other functions (which I named after their posters), I have the following results (on my first generation Intel MacBook Pro):

```
Allen:                  14.6 µs per loop [1]
Terhorst:               26.6 µs per loop
Tarle:                  44.7 µs per loop
ctcherry:               44.8 µs per loop
Etchasketch 1 (short):  64.6 µs per loop
Schinckel:              65.0 µs per loop
Etchasketch 2:          71.6 µs per loop
Little:                 89.4 µs per loop
Tyler:                 179.0 µs per loop
```

[1] Note that Allen modifies the list in place – I believe this has skewed the time, in that the `timeit` module runs the code 100000 times and 99999 of them are with the dupe-less list.

---

**Summary**: Straight-forward implementation with sets wins over confusing one-liners :-)

Comment: james suggested a faster version. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/#91430

Comment: Bump for using OSX. ;-)

Comment: @jfs: Both james and Allen's versions mutate in-place, so unless the microbenchmark used accounts for that (e.g. by calling the functions using a fresh `list` each time and/or including no duplicates at all), the timings aren't comparable. The fastest solutions nowadays (from 3.6 onwards) are either the `unique_everseen` recipe from `itertools` (if you need to process each element as it is found) which is about 10% faster than Terhorst's solution, or, at 40-80% of the runtime of `unique_everseen`, `list(dict.fromkeys(iterable))` (or `lst[:] = dict.fromkeys(lst)` to operate "in place").

Comment: @ShadowRanger: my microbenchmarks include `f(lst[:])` (i.e., the copying happens on each call). Though Python has changed in 12+ years. I would not rely on the microbenchmarks results from so many years ago.

Answer (score 18):

**Update**: [on Python3.7+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835527/4279):

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys('abracadabra'))
['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd']
```

---

<sup>old answer:</sup>

Here is the fastest solution so far (for the following input):

```
def del_dups(seq):
    seen = {}
    pos = 0
    for item in seq:
        if item not in seen:
            seen[item] = True
            seq[pos] = item
            pos += 1
    del seq[pos:]

lst = [8, 8, 9, 9, 7, 15, 15, 2, 20, 13, 2, 24, 6, 11, 7, 12, 4, 10, 18, 
       13, 23, 11, 3, 11, 12, 10, 4, 5, 4, 22, 6, 3, 19, 14, 21, 11, 1, 
       5, 14, 8, 0, 1, 16, 5, 10, 13, 17, 1, 16, 17, 12, 6, 10, 0, 3, 9, 
       9, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 5, 14, 18, 12, 19, 2, 8, 9, 0, 8, 4, 5]
del_dups(lst)
print(lst)
# -> [8, 9, 7, 15, 2, 20, 13, 24, 6, 11, 12, 4, 10, 18, 23, 3, 5, 22, 19, 14, 
#     21, 1, 0, 16, 17]
```

Dictionary lookup is slightly faster then the set's one in Python 3.

Comment: Could you explain why the Dictionary lookup is faster than a test for set membership in this case?

Comment: @Stephen Emslie: I don't know. It might be a benchmark artifact. [Try it yourself](http://ideone.com/FEyrs). A pure speculation: dictionary is a fundamental data structure for CPython (namespaces, classes are/were implemented via dictionaries) therefore dicts are more tuned/optimized than sets.

Comment: Good timing, but wrong conclusion.  The timing shows only that operator access such as ``d[k] = v`` is faster than method call access such as ``d.__setitem__(k, v)`` even if the latter has been pre-bound using ``d_setitem = d.__setitem__`` and then timing ``d_setitem(k, v)``.

Comment: Using Python 3.4, I tried your test script; and the function that uses a set is consistently **slightly** faster.

Comment: @jfs: In 3.6+, this can be made much simpler and [even faster](https://ideone.com/98fKtX) by simplifying to just `def del_dups(seq): seq[:] = dict.fromkeys(seq)` (to modify in-place) or `def del_dups(seq): return list(dict.fromkeys(seq))` to make a new copy without duplicates.

Comment: @ShadowRanger dict order is guaranteed by the language only since Python 3.7. Though it is ok for CPython 3.6+, Pypy implementations. dict.fromkeys is O(n) in memory algorithm unlike O(k) memory solution in the answer

Comment: Please ignore the last remark about the memory (my mistake)

Comment: @jfs: True (on dict order guarantee). I usually include that qualification; forgot this time. There's only one 3.6 supporting interpreter aside from those two that I know of (Stackless Python), no idea what guarantees it has. That said, there *were* some insertion-ordering guarantees made in 3.6 due to PEP 468 and PEP 520 that are much simpler to satisfy if `dict`s are insertion-ordered when no deletions are performed (the only reason they didn't guarantee it in 3.6 was because they weren't sure if they wanted to limit themselves by guaranteeing deletion gaps weren't filled with new elements).

Comment: Since this use of `dict.fromkeys` definitionally doesn't delete from the resulting `dict` before inserting new keys (it makes the `dict`, shallow copies the keys, throws it away), it's *likely* to work in 3.6 interpreters that don't guarantee it, but yes, not guaranteed until 3.7.

Answer (score 15):

What's going to be fastest depends on what percentage of your list is duplicates. If it's nearly all duplicates, with few unique items, creating a new list will probably be faster. If it's mostly unique items, removing them from the original list (or a copy) will be faster.

Here's one for modifying the list in place:

```
def unique(items):
  seen = set()
  for i in xrange(len(items)-1, -1, -1):
    it = items[i]
    if it in seen:
      del items[i]
    else:
      seen.add(it)
```

Iterating backwards over the indices ensures that removing items doesn't affect the iteration.

Comment: This gives different results to the other solutions (the OP didn't specify which is correct), as regards which duplicate to keep.

This solution: [1, 2, 1] -> [2, 1]

Other solutions: [1, 2, 1] -> [1, 2]

Comment: I added a clarification about this in the question text.

Answer (score 10):

This is the fastest in-place method I've found (assuming a large proportion of duplicates):

```
def unique(l):
    s = set(); n = 0
    for x in l:
        if x not in s: s.add(x); l[n] = x; n += 1
    del l[n:]
```

This is 10% faster than Allen's implementation, on which it is based (timed with timeit.repeat, JIT compiled by psyco). It keeps the first instance of any duplicate.

repton-infinity: I'd be interested if you could confirm my timings.

Comment: Dictionaries are slightly faster than sets. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/#282589

Answer (score 7):

Obligatory generator-based variation:

```
def unique(seq):
  seen = set()
  for x in seq:
    if x not in seen:
      seen.add(x)
      yield x
```

Answer (score 7):

This may be the simplest way:

```
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(iterable))
```

As of Python 3.5, OrderedDict is now implemented in C, so this was is now the shortest, cleanest, and fastest.

Comment: Elegant, but unfortunately about a magnitude slower than the fastest solution, and surprisingly one of the slowest solutions in general. The `OrderedDict` seems to be a real performance killer.

Comment: Perhaps if `OrderedSet` ever becomes a builtin we'd have a very fast solution

Answer (score 5):

Taken from http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark

```
def f5(seq, idfun=None):  
    # order preserving 
    if idfun is None: 
        def idfun(x): return x 
    seen = {} 
    result = [] 
    for item in seq: 
        marker = idfun(item) 
        # in old Python versions: 
        # if seen.has_key(marker) 
        # but in new ones: 
        if marker in seen: continue 
        seen[marker] = 1 
        result.append(item) 
    return result
```

Comment: it is slower than corresponding in-place version (at least for some inputs). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/#282589

Answer (score 5):

One-liner:

```
new_list = reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y][:1-int(y in x)], my_list, [])
```

Answer (score 4):

An in-place one-liner for this:

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 2, 'a', 'a', 3]
>>> [ item for pos,item in enumerate(x) if x.index(item)==pos ]
[1, 2, 'a', 3]
```

Comment: HI Mario, How this works, please explain, what I understood is index return only one value, so its unique ?

Comment: The list.index(item) method returns the position of the *first* item found in the list, and comparing this with the actual position of the item (from enumerate) we can therefore tell whether that item is the first occurring or not, keeping only the first occurring.

Comment: Very nice solution. But is it really _in-place_? When you use list comprehension, isn't a new list being created?

Answer (score 4):

This is the fastest one, comparing all the stuff from this [lengthy discussion](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark) and the other answers given here, refering to this [benchmark](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark/uniqifiers_benchmark.py). It's another 25% faster than the fastest function from the discussion, `f8`. Thanks to David Kirby for the idea.

```
def uniquify(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]
```

Some time comparison:

```
$ python uniqifiers_benchmark.py 
* f8_original 3.76
* uniquify 3.0
* terhorst 5.44
* terhorst_localref 4.08
* del_dups 4.76
```

Comment: I don't see time comparison with solutions from the top answers here. In my experience, [explicit loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/89250/4279) are faster than list comprehension in CPython (at least it requires a benchmark to test for each particular case).

Comment: I added the timings above. The main overhead in the presented solutions is the property lookup for add, append and so on, but even if you kick that out, the list comprehension is about 25% faster than `terhorst_localreferences`.

Comment: could you include the complete benchmark code in your answer? I don't see `terhorst` (or any other relevant code) in [the file you linked](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark/uniqifiers_benchmark.py).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/C5SQmT1R

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do something really cool in Python to solve this.  You can create a list comprehension that would reference itself as it is being built.  As follows:

```
   # remove duplicates...
   def unique(my_list):
       return [x for x in my_list if x not in locals()['_[1]'].__self__]
```

Edit: **I removed the "self", and it works on Mac OS X, Python 2.5.1.**

The _[1] is Python's "secret" reference to the new list.  The above, of course, is a little messy, but you could adapt it fit your needs as necessary.  For example, you can actually write a function that returns a reference to the comprehension; it would look more like:

```
return [x for x in my_list if x not in this_list()]
```

---

Comment: The example as given does not compile for me -- the trailing ".__self__" is not valid [[Linux 2.6 w/ Python 2.5.1]]

Comment: Holy cow, you're turning Python into Perl with the magic underscore business. Just say no.

Answer (score 2):

Do the duplicates necessarily need to be in the list in the first place?  There's no overhead as far as looking the elements up, but there is a little bit more overhead in adding elements (though the overhead should be O(1) ).

```
>>> x  = []
>>> y = set()
>>> def add_to_x(val):
...     if val not in y:
...             x.append(val)
...             y.add(val)
...     print x
...     print y
... 
>>> add_to_x(1)
[1]
set([1])
>>> add_to_x(1)
[1]
set([1])
>>> add_to_x(1)
[1]
set([1])
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove duplicates and preserve order:

This is a fast 2-liner that leverages built-in functionality of list comprehensions and dicts.

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 'a', 'a', 3]

tmpUniq = {} # temp variable used below 
results = [tmpUniq.setdefault(i,i) for i in x if i not in tmpUniq]

print results
[1, 2, 'a', 3]
```

The dict.setdefaults() function returns the value as well as adding it to the temp dict directly in the list comprehension.  Using the built-in functions and the hashes of the dict will work to maximize efficiency for the process.

Answer (score 1):

O(n) if dict is hash, O(nlogn) if dict is tree, and simple, fixed.  Thanks to Matthew for the suggestion.  Sorry I don't know the underlying types.

```
def unique(x):    
  output = []
  y = {}
  for item in x:
    y[item] = ""

  for item in x:
    if item in y:
      output.append(item)

  return output
```

Comment: FYI, you can also do that with a set so you don't have to set it equal to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

has_key in python is O(1). Insertion and retrieval from a hash is also O(1). Loops through n items twice, so O(n).

```
def unique(list):
  s = {}
  output = []
  for x in list:
    count = 1
    if(s.has_key(x)):
      count = s[x] + 1

    s[x] = count
  for x in list:
    count = s[x]
    if(count > 0):
      s[x] = 0
      output.append(x)
  return output
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some great, efficient solutions here.  However, for anyone not concerned with the absolute most efficient `O(n)` solution, I'd go with the simple one-liner `O(n^2*log(n))` solution:

```
def unique(xs):
    return sorted(set(xs), key=lambda x: xs.index(x))
```

or the more efficient two-liner `O(n*log(n))` solution:

```
def unique(xs):
    positions = dict((e,pos) for pos,e in reversed(list(enumerate(xs))))
    return sorted(set(xs), key=lambda x: positions[x])
```

Comment: That code is difficult to understand, and you say it's less efficient than the other solutions already presented here. So why would you go with it?

Comment: I consider this easy to understand; passing a lambda function as the key parameter of sorted is really the canonical way to sort a list in Python.  Most of my Python work involves generating reports on lists of statistics, and so to me this seems like the simplest and most Pythonic approach.

Comment: While I agree your solution is succinct, the question asked for the fastest algorithm, not the most Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two recipes from the *itertools* documentation:

```
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return imap(next, imap(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with python, but an algorithm would be to sort the list, then remove duplicates (by comparing to previous items in the list), and finally find the position in the new list by comparing with the old list.

Longer answer: http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Cookbook/Python/Recipe/52560

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def unique(list):
...   y = []
...   for x in list:
...     if x not in y:
...       y.append(x)
...   return y
```

Comment: To explain why: searching for x in a list structure (y) is O(n), while searching for x in a set (or dictionary) is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the empty list from the call to set() in Terhost's answer, you get a little speed boost.

Change:
    found = set([])
to:
    found = set()

However, you don't need the set at all.

```
def unique(items):
    keep = []

    for item in items:
        if item not in keep:
            keep.append(item)

    return keep
```

Using timeit I got these results:

with set([]) -- 4.97210427363
with set() -- 4.65712377445
with no set -- 3.44865284975

Comment: yeah, when you have few data, I bet the set internal mecanisme is slower that iterating over a list. But if you got maaaaaaaaaaany element, I think set are faster. Or what would be the point of this data structures ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [] # Your list  of items that includes Duplicates

# Assuming that your list contains items of only immutable data types

dict_x = {} 

dict_x = {item : item for i, item in enumerate(x) if item not in dict_x.keys()}
# Average t.c. = O(n)* O(1) ; furthermore the dict comphrehension and generator like behaviour of enumerate adds a certain efficiency and pythonic feel to it.

x = dict_x.keys() # if you want your output in list format
```

Comment: What can go wrong with items of mutable types?

Comment: This doesn't work the way you think it does. `if item not in dict_x.keys()` is checking the keys of the original, empty `dict_x`, not the dictionary being created. It's always true. The duplicates are removed simply because trying to create a duplicate key is ignored.

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()`?

Comment: @ByteEater Mutable types can't be used as dictionary keys.

Comment: @Bramar, maybe he tried to enable mutable types by writing `i: item` instead if `item : item` (although a single name for the pair would suffice) and then do `.values()` instead of `.keys()` in both places. But that won't work because of your first comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> x=[1,1,2,'a','a',3]
>>> y = [ _x for _x in x if not _x in locals()['_[1]'] ]
>>> y
[1, 2, 'a', 3]
```

"locals()['_[1]']" is the "secret name" of the list being created.

Comment: Presence of _[1] local is not guaranteed by language.

Comment: "<item> in <list>" is O(n), so this is slow.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this one is fast or not, but at least it is simple.

Simply, convert it first to a set and then again to a list

```
def unique(container):
  return list(set(container))
```

Comment: This does not preserve order.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't done any tests, but one possible algorithm might be to create a second list, and iterate through the first list.  If an item is not in the second list, add it to the second list.

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 'a', 'a', 3]
y = []
for each in x:
    if each not in y:
        y.append(each)
```

Comment: I find your use of the variable name "each" really confusing to read, probably because in many languages it is a keyword. It's much clearer to use item or just i.

Comment: 'i' to me implies an index - we aren't iterating through indices, we are iterating through objects.  I'd prefer item, but I don't see 'each' as bad - just because it is a keyword in another language, why prevent it's use here.  Syntax highlighting (as shown above) picks it up fine...

Comment: Other than AppleScript, what languages use the word 'each' as a keyword?

Comment: You should have used a set. This is unlikely to be the fastest.

Comment: Marcin: "... while preserving order".

Answer (score -2):

One pass.

```
a = [1,1,'a','b','c','c']

new_list = []
prev = None

while 1:
    try:
        i = a.pop(0)
        if i != prev:
            new_list.append(i)
        prev = i
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Comment: Requires sorted input, doesn't it?

Answer (score -2):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,7,8,8,9,9,3,45]

def unique(l):

    ids={}
    for item in l:
        if not ids.has_key(item):
            ids[item]=item
    return  ids.keys()
print a

print unique(a)
```

Inserting elements will take theta(n)
retrieving if element is exiting or not will take constant time
testing all the items will take also theta(n)
so we can see that this solution will take theta(n).
Bear in mind that dictionary in python implemented by hash table.

Comment: The questions says "*while preserving order*". A Python dictionary doesn't preserve order.