# Delete an item from a list

Tags: python, list, unique

Hey, I was trying to delete an item form a list (without using `set`):

```
list1 = []
for i in range(2,101):
    for j in range(2,101):
        list1.append(i ** j)
list1.sort()
for k in range(1,len(list1) - 1):
    if (list1[k] == list1[k - 1]):
        list1.remove(list1[k])
print "length = " + str(len(list1))
```

The `set` function works fine, but i want to apply this method. Except I get:

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

on the statement:

```
 if (list1[k] == list1[k - 1]):
```

---

**Edited to add**
(Thanks to Ned Batchelder) the working code is:

```
list1 = []
for i in range(2,101):
 for j in range(2,101):
   list1.append(i ** j)
list1.sort()
k = 0
while k < len(list1) - 1: # while loop instead of for loop because "The range function is evaluated once before the loop is entered"
 k += 1
 if (list1[k] == list1[k - 1]):
  list1.remove(list1[k])
  list1.sort()
  k -= 1 # "If you find a duplicate, you don't want to move onto the next iteration, since you'll miss potential runs of more than two duplicates"
print "length = " + str(len(list1))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - what set function? What do you mean, "apply this method?"

Comment: I think he wants to not have duplicates in his list.

Comment: The `set` object, like in `s = set( [ 2, 2, 3, 4 ] )` I guess :) Is it homework?

Comment: I presume (hope) that you're just doing this for education purposes?

Comment: @KennyTm: Because i want to know why my method doesn't work.

Comment: @Wayne Werner: Yes, It's a Project Euler problem,I manged to solve it using (set) now i want to solve it my way.

Comment: You haven't actually said what doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you should have said that then, instead of making people guess. (You should also probably try to accept answers to your other questions, and read and vote upon questions)

Comment: @Nick Presta:
if (list1[k] == list1[k - 1]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because in your loop, you are iterating over all the indexes in the original list, but shortening the list as you go.  At the end of the iteration, you will be accessing indexes that no longer exist:

```
for k in range(1,len(list1) - 1):
    if (list1[k] == list1[k - 1]):
        list1.remove(list1[k])
```

The `range` function is evaluated once before the loop is entered, creating a list of all the indexes in the list.  Each call to `remove` shortens the list by one, so if you remove any elements, you're guaranteed to get your error at the end of the list.

If you want to use a loop like this, try:

```
k = 1
while k < len(list1):
    if list1[k] == list1[k-1]:
        del list1[k]
    else:
        k += 1
```

I fixed a few other things:

1. You don't need parentheses around the condition in Python if statements.
2. If you find a duplicate, you don't want to move onto the next iteration, since you'll miss potential runs of more than two duplicates.
3. You want to start from index 1, not zero, since k=0 will access list1[-1].

Comment: - "The range function is evaluated once before the loop is entered"
and "If you find a duplicate, you don't want to move onto the next iteration, since you'll miss potential runs of more than two duplicates."
that the answer i was looking for, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you're trying to uniquify a list (clarification would be awesome) so take a look here: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark

There is also this question here on SO: [In Python, what is the fastest algorithm for removing duplicates from a list so that all elements are unique *while preserving order*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so-t)

Comment: unique and set work fine, my question is: What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing items Write a list comprehension of the things you want in the new list:

```
list1[:] = [list1[k] for k in range(1,len(list1) - 1) 
                     if not list1[k] == list1[k - 1] ]
```

Your method breaks because you remove items from the list. When you do that, the list becomes *shorter* and the next loop iteration has skipped a item. Say you look at k=0 and L = [1,2,3]. You delete the first item, so L = [2,3] and the next k=1. So you look at L[1] which is 3 -- you skipped the 2!

So: **Never change the list you iterate on**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `del` :

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
del l[2]
print l
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Why a -1 ? I might have not understood the question in the first place then ?

Comment: del and list1.remove are the same.
The problem isn't here !