# An interesting code for obtaining unique values from a list

Tags: python

Say given a list `s = [2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]`

I saw the following code being used to obtain unique values from s:

```
unique_s = sorted(unique(s))
```

where unique is defined as:

```
def unique(seq): 
    # not order preserving 
    set = {}
    map(set.__setitem__, seq, []) 
    return set.keys()
```

I'm just curious to know if there is any difference between this and just doing list(set(s))? Both results in a mutable object with the same values.

I'm guessing this code is faster since it's only looping once rather than twice in the case of type conversion?

Comment: use code button for post code

Comment: I believe the code above was (is) used with (to support) python version prior to 2.3 when set() didn't exist yet.

Comment: Not a python guy, so not posting this as an answer, but it looks like they do the same thing, other than the fact that doing list(set(s)) is probably not guaranteed to preserve the order, whereas when you call unique_s=sorted(unique(s)) it seems to preserve order

Comment: Well, there's an obvious difference in that `list(set(s))` is giving you a sorted result just by chance :P

Comment: I meant the difference between the unique() function and list(set(s)). I know list() is not order preserving.

Comment: Even without set this could be much simpler: `def unique(seq): return dict.fromkeys(seq).keys()`

Comment: related: [In Python, what is the fastest algorithm for removing duplicates from a list so that all elements are unique *while preserving order*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the code you describe:

```
list(set(s))
```

This works on all Pythons from 2.4 (I think) to 3.3, is concise, and uses built-ins in an easy to understand way.

The function `unique` appears to be designed to work if `set` is not a built-in, which is true for Python 2.3.  Python 2.3 is fairly ancient (2003).  The `unique` function is also broken for the Python 3.x series, since `dict.keys` returns an iterator for Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

For a *sorted* sequence you could use [`itertools` unique_justseen() recipe](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools#itertools-recipes) to get unique values while preserving order:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

print map(itemgetter(0), groupby([2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]))
# -> [2, 3, 4]
```

To remove duplicate items from a sorted sequence inplace (to leave only unique values):

```
def del_dups(sorted_seq):
    prev = object()
    pos = 0
    for item in sorted_seq:
        if item != prev:
            prev = item
            sorted_seq[pos] = item
            pos += 1
    del sorted_seq[pos:]

L = [2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
del_dups(L)
print L # -> [2, 3, 4]
```