# How can I make my code be a set?

Tags: python

I have a little code that takes a list of objects, and only outputs the items in the list that are unique.

This is my code

```
def only_once(a):
    return [x for x in a if a.count(x) is 1]
```

My teacher requires us to use sets for this function though.
Can someone show me what I can do?

My code has to take an input such as a=[1,4,6,7,3,2,4,5,7,5,6], and output [1,  3,  2]. Has to retain it's order also.

Comment: Sets don't preserve order, so I can't really see how a set will be helpful here aside from providing fast `in` functionality.

Comment: @Blender: you can use sets and preserve order: [In Python, what is the fastest algorithm for removing duplicates from a list so that all elements are unique *while preserving order*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I'm assuming that you're also user1744238 and user1744316 -- please pick a username and stick to it, that way it's easier to check to see what variants of a question you've asked and what you've already tried.]

One set-based approach is to use two sets as a counter.  You only care about whether you've seen something once or more than once.  For example, here's an easy-to-explain approach:

1. Make an empty set for `once` and `more`.
2. Loop over every element of your list, and:

   1. If you haven't seen it before, add it to `once`.
   2. If you've seen it once, remove it from `once` and add it to `more`.
3. Now you know what elements you've seen exactly once, in the set `once`.
4. Loop over the elements of the list, and if you've seen it once, add it to the output list, and remove it from the `once` set so you don't output the same element twice.

This gives me:

```
In [49]: f([1,4,6,7,3,2,4,5,7,5,6])
Out[49]: [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: thank you very much, I agree with Blender. Very helpful, trying to build using this

Comment: This is essentially the algorithm I used in my post (yes, I ignored the homework aspect of this) except that I don't bother to remove items from "once" since you can just invert the check and use "more".

Comment: @agf: yep, that's the better way.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, what you want is a set of items that appear once, and only once.

The best option here is to use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), as it means you only count the items once, rather than once per item, greatly increasing performance:

```
>>> import collections
>>> {key for key, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count == 1}
{1, 2, 3}
```

We simply replace the square brackets with curly braces to signify a set comprehension over a list comprehension, to get a set of results.

Comment: I already have a method of doing it, I just need it to be a method using set()

Comment: Indeed, previous to 2.7, you can use the ``set()`` constructor with a generator expression instead.

Comment: I think that using Counter and a set comprehension obfuscate the algorithm, which is important for a beginner to understand.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to remove any item that is in the list more than once, not just occurences after the first, you can use:

```
# without using generators / comprehensions
def only_once(iterable):
    seen = set()
    duplicates = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item in seen:
            duplicates.add(item)
        seen.add(item)
    result = []
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in duplicates:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

For general order-preserving duplicate elimination, see `unique_everseen` in the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

Comment: +1, I looked in ``itertools`` as I was sure there was something for this, and didn't see this one. The best solution here.