# python using set to create list of elements that only appear once

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make my code be a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886450/how-can-i-make-my-code-be-a-set)
>   [python takes list and returns only if negative value also exists using set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887398/python-takes-list-and-returns-only-if-negative-value-also-exists-using-set)

Basically I have a huge list:

```
# with (n) being a number in the hundreds of thousands or millions
def big_list(n):
return [ randrange(n) for i in range(n) ]
```

What I need to do is create a new list containing only the elements of `big_list(n)` that appear once using `set`. I'm really stuck so anything that could point me in the right direction would be awesome!

Comment: This is exactly the same as [How can I make my code be a set? - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886450/how-can-i-make-my-code-be-a-set-python)

Comment: You're right, haha looks like I'm not the only one in my class thats confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
l
Out[225]: [1, 2, 3, 45, 2, 2, 34, 5, 64, 5, 6, 45, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 64, 3]

[x for x in l if l.count(x)==1]
Out[226]: [34, 4]
```

or use defaultdict from the collections,if perfomance matters:

```
In [228]: import collections
     ...: d = collections.defaultdict(int)
     ...: for x in l: d[x] += 1
     ...: results = [x for x in l if d[x] == 1]
     ...: 

In [229]: results
Out[229]: [34, 4]
```

Comment: This will have horrible performance on a big list.

Comment: @ Liquid_Fire -- yes, it's n^2 i think, the second should be better.

Answer (score 1):

Store the counting in a dict and filter the elements with `count==1`, dict keys are already unique.

[update]

Untested, please fix any bug yourself:

```
def filter_single_elements(big_list):
    counter = {}
    for element in big_list:
        counter[element] = counter.get(element, 0) + 1
    new_list = []
    for element, count in counter.items():
        if count == 1:
            new_list.append(element)
    return new_list
```

This returns a new list. You may try to make a generator instead:

```
def filter_single_elements_iter(big_list):
    counter = {}
    for element in big_list:
        counter[element] = counter.get(element, 0) + 1
    for element, count in counter.items():
        if count == 1:
            yield element
```

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail on how I would be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want only the items that appear exactly once in the big list. Here is how you can do it (where `x` is your list):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
>>> y = []
>>>
>>> for item, count in Counter(x).most_common():
...     if count == 1:
...         y.append(item)
...
>>> y
[2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Note that `collections.Counter` is 2.7+ only.

Answer (score 0):

use a generator expression in the set constructor:

```
def big_list(n):
    return set(randrange(n) for i in xrange(n))
```

**EDIT**

As the comment bellow pointed out, you seek elements that appear once.
I suggest you have a look at [counter object](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects). You can use them for efficient tallying of the elements in your big list, and than iterate over the counter to sieve out the ones you need.

Comment: The OP is looking for elements that appear once, not one of each element that appears. Also, in 2.7+, you can use a set comprehension (``{randrange(n) for i in xrange(n)}``).

Answer (score 0):

Convert big_list into a generator and apply [the unique_everseen recipe from itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns each element once, not each element that has a count of 1.