# python takes list and returns only if negative value also exists using set

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

Basically I have a big list:

```
# where (n) is over a couple hundred thousand or is 1 million
def big_list(n):
    return [ randrange(-n//3,n//3) for i in range(n) ]
```

And using a `set` I must return a new list if and only if its negative value also exists.

Ex. if `list = [-3,-2,-1,2,1,4]`
it should return `new_list = [2,1]`

I must do this using `set`, and I''m really lost.

Comment: how much more homework do you have?

Comment: I just removed my answer ... I didnt think and didnt realize that this was homework ... dont really want to spoil his learning experience...

Comment: Given large set of positive and negative numbers return a new list with only the positive numbers that also had a negative "twin" in the original list. An interesting question, but when you say _I must do this using set_ hints that this may be a homework question. Is that the case?

Comment: Most certainly is homework. I guess I have been abusing this site in the last couple hours, sorry about that. Last couple weeks of class have kind of gone over my head. I'm working on it though (getting extra help twice a week) Thanks for all the help anyways!Hopefully I'll be in the position to help some one out in the future.

Comment: @JoranBeasley:  We shouldn't be taking responsibility for this academic experience.  If they want to use answers from here as verbatim answers on his homework, that's on them.  In terms of SO, I'm not entirely sure how useful it is.  Not yet, anyway.

Comment: Fyi, don't call any of your variables `list` (or `dict` or `set`). It shadows the built-in name and while it's fine with some names (such as `id`) it's a really bad idea to do so for something as common as `list`.

Comment: @iamtesla If you come clean that it's homework and show us where you're stuck, we can help you out with pointers in the right direction. But if we outright solve your homework problems for you, what is the point of the homework?

Comment: @Liquid_Fire I guess it didn't make it clear enough it was homework, honestly, was not trying to hide that but in hindsight you're right I should have made that clear. And I do agree it's jsut that the past weeks have been tough for me and I've fallen to far behind to even start this assignment by myself. Nonetheless, I'll be sure to try my hardest and get as far as I possibly can by myself before I ask you guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

Store all negative numbers in a set and then get the intersection with the initial list:

```
negatives = set(-x for x in data if x < 0)
numbers_with_negatives = negatives.intersection(data)
```

Demo:

```
>>> data
[-3, -2, -1, 2, 1, 4]
>>> negatives = set(-x for x in data if x < 0)
>>> negatives
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> negatives.intersection(data)
set([1, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you! I need it return the negative values as well but I'll try to figure that out by myself.

Comment: You already know they exist, so you can use a list comprehension that simply negates each value from the original list. You could also use `map` with `operator.neg` on the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `set` from a list created with `big_list()`, you can use it to create a desired result list by iterating through all the elements of the set and selecting all those whose values are > 0 and whose negative value is also in the set.

You can use a [list display](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-displays) expression, commonly call a "list comprehension", to create the resultant list with one long-ish line of code inside `[]` brackets, like the `big_list()` function does.

Hope this helps.