# How to get only unique values from a list in Python

Tags: python

So i want to do choose only the unique character of an array , the desired output is suppose to be :

Input : 4,5,6,4,2,2,9

Output : 5,6,9

I tried these code :

```
arr = [4,5,6,4,2,2,9]
unique = list(set(arr))
```

But the output is : 4,5,6,2,9

Is it possible to do it without numpy?

Comment: The title and body of this question seem to be unrelated.

Comment: I edited it, Sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python using set to create list of elements that only appear once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887042/python-using-set-to-create-list-of-elements-that-only-appear-once)

Comment: If you find an answer useful, then please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the frequency of the elements and pick the elements with frequency of one as follows.

```
from collections import Counter
arr = ...
unique = [k for k,v in Counter(arr).items() if v == 1]
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but can you actually tell me how Counter works?

Comment: Since counting is a common use case, Python provides the `Counter` class to facilitate counting.  It is a subclass of `dict` that is specialized to count hashable objects and maintain the object frequency.  As for how it counts, [it merely iterates thru the iterable and counts the elements](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e63cc2f64668bd1d4581f8efa7089af7e08863b8/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L478) :) For more details, please refer to its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter from collections. Here is an example python code:

```
from collections import Counter
arr = [4,5,6,4,2,2,9]
d = Counter(arr)
unique = [x for x in d if d[x] == 1]
print(a)
```

Counter return a dictionary where, array item as a Key and item frequency as a value. For example, if array `arr = [4,5,6,4,2,2,9]` then counter provide following dictionary:

```
d = {
1: 2, 
2: 1, 
3: 1, 
4: 1,
5: 3,
6: 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing returns all numbers in the array, just without duplication.
You can do what you want like this:

`[x for x in array if array.count(x) == 1]`

But thats not very efficient, because it needs to scan the entire array 
for every count() called. A faster way is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)  # count how many times every number appears in the array, for example {5:1, 6:1, 9:1, 4:2, 2:2}. defaultdict(int) means that values default to 0.
for x in arr:
    counts[x] += 1
result = [number for number, count in counts.items() if count == 1 ]
```