# How to remove duplicate pdf files from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, file, pdf

I have a list containing the pdf files

```
l=['ab.pdf', 'cd.pdf', 'ef.pdf', 'gh.pdf']
```

Out of these four files few are duplicate only names are changed, how to delete those file from the list ?

for example ab.pdf and cd.pdf are same, so the final output will be

```
l=['ab.pdf', 'ef.pdf', 'gh.pdf']
```

I have tried filecmp library but it only tells if two files are duplicate.

How to do it most efficiently in pythonic way ?

Comment: How would I know that they're duplicates? :|

Comment: they should be having same contents

Comment: And how do I know that? I don't have the contents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, what is the fastest algorithm for removing duplicates from a list so that all elements are unique \*while preserving order\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so)

Comment: @KallolSamanta You could check memory size (could be bug prone) but if it is a small scale project that would work. You can also just read all the text using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-pdf-files-in-python/) and compare the text.

Comment: What issue are you having with `filecmp`? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse filecmp just says if two files are duplicate, I can use a loop and get the job done, but I dont want to use the loop, I am looking for some effective to get it done.

Comment: @KallolSamanta filecmp is the most effective though, and  don't you want to check for duplicates.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse i don't want to use any loop

Comment: @KallolSamanta you can't iterate over a list without a loop. Why you don't want to use loops?

Comment: It's OK to note in a question why it is not a duplicate, but one has to explain how it is different from the proposed duplicate(s). Merely stating that it is different is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to tell the computer the path of the files in your computer and compare the files one by one, although it sounds not such effective.

Comment: I could do that, but i dont't want to use any loop, I am looking for alternative effective way.

Comment: I can't find a way without any loop.  Tell me if you find a better way without any loop!