# Are dict comprehensions evaluated incrementally in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment, dictionary-comprehension

I'd have assumed the results of `purge` and `purge2` would be the same in the following code (remove duplicate elements, keeping the first occurrences and their order):

```
def purge(a):
    l = []
    return (l := [x for x in a if x not in l])
def purge2(a):
    d = {}
    return list(d := {x: None for x in a if x not in d})
t = [2,5,3,7,2,6,2,5,2,1,7]
print(purge(t), purge2(t))
```

But it looks like with `dict` comprehensions, unlike with lists, the value of `d` is built incrementally. Is this what's actually happening? Do I correctly infer the semantics of `dict` comprehensions from this sample code and their difference from `list` comprehensions? Does it work only with comprehensions, or also with other right-hand sides referring to the dictionary being assigned to (e.g. comprehensions nested inside other expressions, something involving iterators, comprehensions of types other than `dict`)? Where is it specified and full semantics can be consulted? Or is it just an undocumented behaviour of the implementation, not to be relied upon?

Comment: A dictionary can't have duplicate keys. It's just ignoring the duplicates that you're trying to add, the `if` has no effect.

Comment: You get the same result with `return list({x: None for x in a})`

Comment: Oh, now that you mention it, it's so obvious. Thanks! Care to make it an answer, so I'll accept?

Comment: I took it from [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so/25958705#25958705) and simplified. Which made me not notice the possibility of further simplification.

Comment: Moreover, the value of d is not updated during the comprehensions. To achieve an incremental, usually you want to write explictly a for loop, or use a lambda that captures d in its scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing "incremental" going on here. The walrus operator doesn't assign to the variable until the dictionary comprehension completes. `if x not in d` is referring to the original empty dictionary, not the dictionary that you're building with the comprehension, just as the version with the list comprehension is referring to the original `l`.

The reason the duplicates are filtered out is simply because dictionary keys are always unique. Trying to create a duplicate key simply ignores the second one. It's the same as if you'd written:

```
return {2: None, 2: None}
```

you'll just get `{2: None}`.

So your function can be simplified to

```
def purge2(a):
    return list({x: None for x in a})
```